# Let $ S $ be the set $ \mathbb {R} ^ 2 $ with the origin removed, show that $ \vec{0} $ is a boundary point of $ S $.

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, solution-verification, vector-analysis

Definition. Boundary Points. Let $A\subset \mathbb{R}^n$. A point $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$  is called a boundary point of A if every neighborhood of $x$ contains at least one point in $A$ and atleast one point not in $A$.

Let $ S $ be the set $ \mathbb {R} ^ 2 $ with the origin removed, show that $ \vec{0} $ is a boundary point of $ S $.

Proof. To show that $ \vec{0} = (0, \: 0) $ we have to show that for all $ \varepsilon> 0 $ the following is true for the interval $ I = (0- \varepsilon, \: 0 + \varepsilon) $:

$$ I \cap (0, \: 0) \neq \emptyset \wedge I \cap S \neq \emptyset $$

Clearly, $ 0 - \frac{\epsilon} {2} <0 $, since $ \epsilon> 0 $ and $ 0- \frac{\epsilon}{2}> 0- \epsilon $. This means:

$$0- \frac{\epsilon}{2} \in I \wedge 0- \frac{\epsilon}{2} \notin (0, \: 0)$$

Similarly, for $ x = 0 + \frac {\varepsilon} {2} $ we have

$$x \in I,\: x \in (0, \: 0)$$

This proves that $ (0, \: 0) $ is a boundary point of $ S $

It's okay? Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

Well,  while it's a nice try, you seem to have assumed,  incorrectly,  that a neighborhood of the origin is, or contains,  an *interval* in $\mathbb R^{\color {red}{1}} $.

So, instead you should show that any *ball* in $\mathbb R^{\color {blue}{2}} $ containing  $\vec0$ intersects $\mathbb R^2\setminus\{\vec0\} $.

You're off by one dimension,  and should point out how you pass to an interval.

Comment: I got confused. From the definition, since $ \vec{0} \notin S $ is a boundary point if every neighborhood or ball of $ \vec{0} $ contains at least one point of $ S $. But we are talking about $ \vec{0} $, so yes, every neighborhood or ball has at least one $ S $ point.

Comment: Yes indeed it does.  One way to see it is that $\{\vec0\}$ is not open.